# Why I have a dot when I convert my dataframe to a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples

I have a data frame with three columns `car_store, car_model and quantity`.
Given the `car_model` and the `minimum quantity`, I want to return the `car_store and quantity` for all entries that have the `quantity >= minimum_quantity` in a list of tuples.

What I am doing is:

```
    car_model_quantity_filter = dataframe[(dataframe['car_model'] == car_model ) & (dataframe['quantity'] >= quantity)].sort_values(by=['quantity'], ascending=False, inplace=False)

    car_store_quantity_tuple = car_model_quantity_filter [['car_store','quantity']].to_records(index=False)

    return car_store_quantity_tuple
```

I have almost succeeded doing that, but my output is like:

```
[('Store A', 210.) ('Store B', 149.) ('Store C', 100.)]
```

Where the dot `.` after the number comes from? How to remove it?

Feel free to suggest other approach to filter the data.

Comment: have you checked `df.dtypes` to see if your quantity column is actually a float?  If so, is it possible you have null values in your quantity column?

Comment: There's no float, all entries that have a value is a int value. And yes, I have some entries with null value. Is this the root cause of the `.` ? How to solve it?

Comment: If you have null values in an int column, it will become a float column.  Just because it doesn't look like a float doesn't mean it's not.  You need to check the column dtype.

Comment: I've added this filter to remove the null values but still got the same result: 
`dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['quantity'].isnull() == False]`.
I checked the data type, but I think I'm doing something wrong here. I did: `print(type(dataframe['quantity']))` and I'm getting `Series` as result

Comment: after you drop nulls try `dataframe['quantity'] = dataframe['quantity'].astype(int)`

Comment: Would it be ok by you if you convert the float into integer? Something like this? `[(element[0], int(element[1])) for element in car_store_quantity_tuple]`

Comment: The solution provided by @Chris worked fine(thanks!), but I'm getting a warning with that approach. I'm trying to work around it now:
`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: You can basically ignore that warning if memory is not your issue.